# How can I keep my dwarves from becoming icicles?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I'm trying to dig down through an aquifer in deep winter and my dwarves keep getting frozen into the blocks of ice. I've tried designating the channeling in different manners, but I can't seem to keep them from digging out the area and then jumping in right before the water from the surrounding aquifer squares flash freezes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You hopefully have a burrow defined that encompasses your fortress interior, for sieges and whatnot?  Try extending that burrow so it covers the current surface of the aquifer, but not the z-layer beneath, and set the civilian alert level to restrict to the burrow.  With a little luck that will cause your dwarves to treat the freshly channeled-open hole as forbidden and avoid jumping down into it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try carrying out channeling in summer only; the water might freeze more slowly then.

Comment: This won't work, we're talking about an aquifer here, which means instant flooding and corresponding drowning.

Comment: @alexanderpas Drowning's much more survivable than freezing is.  Occasional, nonfatal submerging is normal when breaching an aquifer.  With freezing, though, the dwarf's gone instantly.